# Android, ошибка "Program type already present" при попытке подключить библиотеку "chronos"

Tags: android, gradle

Пишу ученический проект, возникла необходимость в библиотеке chronos. Получил ошибку. Прямой ответ не гуглится.

Мои шаги по порядку.

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку chronos:

```
implementation 'com.redmadrobot:chronos:1.0.7'
```

https://github.com/RedMadRobot/Chronos

Получаю:

```
Program type already present: org.intellij.lang.annotations.JdkConstants$PatternFlags
```

Гуглю доки.

Нахожу:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes

Конкретно:

This error typically occurs due to one of the following circumstances:

1)A binary dependency includes a library that your app also includes as a direct dependency. For example, your app declares a direct dependency on Library A and Library B, but Library A already includes Library B in its binary.

To resolve this issue, remove Library B as a direct dependency.

2)Your app has a local binary dependency and a remote binary dependency on the same library.

To resolve this issue, remove one of the binary dependencies.

Понимаю, что мой пункт - первый. Ок.

Идём в исходники chronos, и видим там пакет:

```
org.intellij.lang.annotations
```

Ок. Отключить его на этапе компиляции и всё.
Пишем:

```
implementation ('com.redmadrobot:chronos:1.0.7') {
        exclude module: 'org.intellij.lang.annotations'
    }
```

Не помогает.
Ок, отключим проблемный момент на уровне проекта.

```
configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.intellij.lang' , module:'annotations'
}
```

Не помогает.
Пока финиш.
Что я делаю не так?

**app.gradle** модуля на данный момент:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.it.ru.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.muddzdev:styleabletoast:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.patrickpissurno:ripple-effect:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.azoft.carousellayoutmanager:carousel:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'

    implementation 'com.gtomato.android.library:carouselview:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.beloo.widget:ChipsLayoutManager:0.3.7@aar'
    implementation 'com.robertlevonyan.view:MaterialChipView:1.2.5'

    implementation 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'

    implementation 'com.github.pchmn:MaterialChipsInput:1.0.8'

    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.3.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'

    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chuross:expandable-layout:1.0.5'

    implementation 'com.codesgood:justifiedtextview:1.1.0'

    implementation ('com.redmadrobot:chronos:1.0.7') {
        exclude module: 'org.intellij.lang.annotations'
    }
}
```

**Уровень проекта:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

configurations {
    cleanedAnnotations
    compile.exclude group: 'org.intellij.lang' , module:'annotations'
}
```

Comment: А попробуйте на всякие вставить `configurations { ...` на уровне `gradle app`, а не на уровне проекта ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/49981467 ), и уберите `exclude module: 'org.intellij.lang.annotations'`.

Comment: Пробовал, не помогло.